# Multithreading KNeighborsClassifier.kneighbours in python?

Tags: scikit-learn, python-multiprocessing, knn

Finding the Kneighbours of the given data is taking lot of time for huge database search of >10,000 data points.

I am using knn classifier. I read that approximate knn is suited for large scale data.

But, i want to know how to enable multithreading in general for KNeighborsClassifier.kneighbours function to find the nearest neighbours for a given point in less time?

Comment: Your only chance is to use the ```n_jobs``` argument. But i doubt it helps looking for a single query, but querying multiple (rows). A code-analysis would answer that. There is also a huge discussion [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/4009). (remark: knn normaly scales not that bad with the number of samples; but the feature-dimension can be critical!)

Comment: Hi @sascha, n_jobs is in training step: knn_clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=n_neighbors, algorithm=knn_algo, weights='distance',n_job=-1) .But,  I am asking to parallelize this step: closest_distances = knn_clf.kneighbors(give_data_to_predict, n_neighbors=1) in prediction phase.

Comment: If my database has 50k samples, finding the closest distance from given_data_to_predict is taking lot of time even though i used n_jobs to all cores during training step. Actually n_jobs in traning has no influence when i save the tranied model and try to just predict the given data from the saved classfier model.

Comment: May be i have to change question and add more details like how to make my prediction fast. With 500 samples, it takes 3 seconds on my 8 core cpu machine. With 16k samples, it is taking 45seconds. I want to decrease this time.

Comment: That's possible but i don't know what you are trying to say. I mentioned both dimensions in regards to algorithmic-complexity. You still keep mentioning the less important one. Searching on 1d is logn (as an example). But high-dims are critical. That's by design and has nothing to do with sklearn's implementation (in terms of exact methods). If n_jobs is not providing enough speedup, you can't do anything besides modifying sklearn (and in this case this will be complex. KDTrees and co are somewhat serial).

Comment: Ah, my single data point is a 128 list of values like [1 2 3....128].

Comment: (Adressing deleted comment) No. I think i made it clear, that metric-trees have some limits. No matter what implementation. In sklearn-world, this is tackled somewhat [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#k-d-tree). It's a theory-problem! For approximate approaches, there are many alternatives and i think sklearn's got deprecated. In this regard, one might leave sklearn. Start [here](https://github.com/erikbern/ann-benchmarks).

Comment: why dont you post it as answer ? You are the only person who responds first for my every knn related question with references :D

Comment: I don't feel good posting answers when i do think questions are somewhat broad. Let's hope, potential readers will find something useful in the comments. And don't be deceived by the fact i reacted to two of your questions. There are some real metric-tree experts lurking here (e.g. core-devs of sklearn's implementation)